# Getting Organization Id in a Lightning Web Component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I found you can get the current user id like this:

`import id from '@salesforce/user/Id';`

I have a really simple component where all I need are the User Id and the current Org Id. I haven't been able to find any documentation on any simple way to get the Org Id without having to go to Apex. Is this possible? It would be quite unfortunate if you really have to create an apex class and a method just to get the current org id...

Comment: I guess $Organization global variable only works in Visualforce and not in lightning. In lightning, you need to create an apex controller and fetch the org id in the controller.
 
String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();

Comment: Oh no, this cannot still be the way to do it... -.-

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an apex class and a method just to get the current org id. An example:

**UserUtility.apxc**

```apex
public with sharing class UserUtility {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getOrganizationId() {
        return UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    }
}
```

**getOrganizationId.js**

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc'; 
import getOrganizationId from '@salesforce/apex/UserUtility.getOrganizationId';

export default class GetOrganizationId extends LightningElement {

    @wire(getOrganizationId) 
    organizationIdResponse;
}
```

**getOrganizationId.html**

```html
<...>
<p>{organizationIdResponse.data}</p>
<...>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/199355)

Comment: @identigral "What you're asking for cannot be done" _is_ a valid answer.

Comment: @DerekF Considering that a comment of the same nature has been made in 2022, the answer might be valid but it's not useful. A useful answer would show the few required lines of Apex + JS.

Comment: @identigral, sorry for my error. I'll do it better next time... I hope.

Comment: @DerekF, thanks for your support.

Comment: @JoseBlancoPérez Thanks for the updated answer, upvoted.